# amazon scraping script use more than 10GB of internet package .python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

i have 2500 product in CSV file for amazon product and using selenium to open each one to sure if the price changed or not .
the script work well but the problem that it take 10GB of internet package and it's to much.

how to reduce it's using of internet .

i am using chrome webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how pricing works in amazon but can you tell if you are downloading the file(s) every time you read it. Using selenium with chrome also uses too much resources when running it only once for 2500 files.

You may want to check if it is necessary to use selenium to download the CSVs?
You may find other alternative language or library to process the CSV's in a more efficient way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use headless browser for scraping. As there will be no GUI component to load it will reduce your web traffic a lot. And you will end up saving to internet data.

Can create your driver like blow for headless chrome browser:

```
ch_Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ch_Options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('<path to driver .exe>',options=ch_Options)
```